# Why does my CSS animation work in every browser except for Safari?

Tags: html, css, safari

My CSS animation works on every single browser except for Safari. Could someone tell me why this is, or what changes I need to make for it to work universally?

```
    #job-title:before {
        content: '';
        animation-name: animate;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        animation-timing-function: linear;
        animation-duration: 4s;
        animation-delay: 1s;
    }

    @keyframes animate {
        0% {
            content: "Web Developer.";
        }
        50% {
            content: "Web Designer.";
        }
        100% {
            content: "Graphic Designer.";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Safari doesn't work with all things

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to include `-webkit` prefix for the animation?

```css
#job-title:before {
  content: '';
  -webkit-animation-name: animate;
  animation-name: animate;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate {
  0% {
    content: "Web Developer.";
  }
  50% {
    content: "Web Designer.";
  }
  100% {
    content: "Graphic Designer.";
  }
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    content: "Web Developer.";
  }
  50% {
    content: "Web Designer.";
  }
  100% {
    content: "Graphic Designer.";
  }
}
```